# if $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=L$, find $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(ax^{2}+x)=L$

Tags: real-analysis

If $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=L$, find $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(ax^{2}+x)$.
Because $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=L$, can I conclude that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(ax^{2}+x)=L$ ?

Comment: I think it might depend on the function. For example if $f(x) = (x+1)^\infty$, there might varying results based on the input, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: what do you mean by $(x+1)^{\infty}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that by setting $f(0)=L$ you obtain
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}f(ax^2+x)=f\left(\lim_{x\to 0}ax^2+x\right)=f(0)=L
$$
by continuity of $f$ in zero (which is exactly your assumption).

Comment: Is it ok to assume continuity?

Comment: It is not ok to assume continuity

Comment: The assumption is NOT continuity at $0$.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: If you set $f(0)=L$ that will make $f$ continuous in zero and you can use the computation in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use limit rule for composition of functions:

Suppose $\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)=y_0,\lim_{y\to y_0}f(x)=L$, and there exists $\delta>0$, such that $g(x)\not=y_0$ for all $x\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)\setminus \{x_0\}$, then we know

$\lim_{x\to x_0}f\circ g(x)=L.$

For your questions, let $g(x)=ax^2+x$. You can check the assumptions are satisfied. So the result holds.